# How to create an email address on your domain dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, web-hosting

I want to send emails to users based on a topic. Let's say they create a topic called Vacation. I want to be able to send them an email via vacation@yourdomain.com, which they will be able to reply to(I have enabled my app to receive email messages). 
How can I create this email account dynamically through my domain host(in this case namecheap ) in a Rails app?

[IDonethis](http://idonethis.com) has this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure a mail server host on your own server or use the API of your host service.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I was over thinking this. Didn't realize Namecheap had an API I could interact with.

Comment: Namecheap API rocks !

Comment: @ShivamD if you can share your code for that, it would be great.

Comment: Here is a blog post from @ShivamD how he finally implemented it: http://blog.shivamdaryanani.com/blog/2013/11/14/creating-email-accounts-on-your-domain-dynamically/

Comment: Is the Namecheap API to generate new emails on the go still available ?

Comment: Please provide a more detailed response to this as this fails to cover how even to use the Namecheap API? According to Namecheap, they do not do that officially . Please provide feedback if I am wrong or missing the point here.